# How to change partitioned table into non-partitioned table in oracle along with data and indexes?

Tags: database, oracle

I've done this in following  ways:

1. Help of Oracle data pump (expdp/impdp) utility with option `PARTITION_OPTIONS=merge`.
2. And `ALTER TABLE t1 MERGE PARTITIONS p01 TO p04 INTO p0;` (*Here I merged successfully but all stored in one partitioned which I don't want in that way*.)
3. Create a temporary copy of table along with data, drop the original table and rename the temp table name into the original. (*This approach may not good for huge data*)

But here all I want to know, Is there any way to achieve this from `SQL>` Prompt with oneliner command /statement? So, the data could be stored in table/tablespace without any partitioning things.

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST SOLUTION:**

do a partition exchange, let's say you have the following partitionned table:

```
create table tpart (
  x int,
 y int
) partition by range (x) (
  partition p0 values less than (10),
 partition p1 values less than (20)
);
```

Create a new non-partitionned table with same columns:

```
create table new_table(
  x int,
 y int
);
```

Then exchange your partitions with the new tables:

```
alter table tpart exchange partition p0 with table new_table including indexes update indexes;
alter table tpart exchange partition p1 with table new_table including indexes update indexes;
```

**SECOND SOLUTION:**

pre-create the table in the destination schema without the partitioning and import data with datapump using: table_exists_action=append